# Filter Gridview based on cell text

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How shall i write the code to filter gridview by Order_status where text= Pending and Paid ?
here is my templatefield

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Status" SortExpression="Order_status">
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Order_status") %>' > 
         <asp:ListItem>Pending</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Paid</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Shipped</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Cancelled</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"Text='<%# Bind("Order_status") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

here is my entity data source

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EDS_Orders" runat="server" EnableUpdate="true" EnableFlattening="False"  OrderBy="it.Order_date DESC"
                      ConnectionString="name=Bohemian1Entities" DefaultContainerName="Bohemian1Entities" EntitySetName="t_customer_orders"
                      where="it.Order_status = Pending and paid">       

</asp:EntityDataSource>
```